# Got this error when i used the command manager server

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, web-applications

I am building a dashboard project currently using Django so that I can learn it as well. I am following a tutorial and did as they did it but I am getting this error right now. I am not sure where I went wrong so please anything helps!!

**Error Message**

```
C:\Users\Vignesh\.vscode\Interview Dashboard\dashboard> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
October 15, 2022 - 15:01:34
Django version 4.1.2, using settings 'dashboard.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[15/Oct/2022 15:01:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10681
[15/Oct/2022 15:01:55] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[15/Oct/2022 15:01:55] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
[15/Oct/2022 15:01:55] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[15/Oct/2022 15:01:55] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
C:\Users\Vignesh\.vscode\Interview Dashboard\dashboard\dashboard\urls.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 717, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 495, in check
    messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 725, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'base.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\Vignesh\\.vscode\\Interview Dashboard\\dashboard\\base\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

**base.urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    
    urspattern = [
        path('', views.pplList, name='ppl'),
    ]
```

**dashboard.urls.py**

```
"""dashboard URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls'))
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, render

# Create your views here.
def pplList(request):
    return HttpResponse('Candidate List')
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'nase.apps.Config',
]
```

Comment: what tutorial do you follow? Maybe you forgot something in code. In question you could  add link to tutorial. But we can't see tutorial so we also don't know where you went wrong

Comment: in `base.urls.py` you have typo: `urspattern` - but it should be `urlpatterns` - you forgot char `l` in `urls` and char `s` at the end of `patterns`